# Direct antonyms of bifurcate / trifurcate?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for two words that would describe:

- merge from two branches or forks;
- merge from three branches or forks.

PS: am I "allowed" to continue the respective series by applying different numbers in Latin?

Comment: Research: so far I have found "biconverge".

Comment: One merely reverses metaphoric direction and uses _bifurcate_ and _trifurcate_ again. Note that _20 miles east of Logan, the freeway bifurcates_ can refer to either changing from 1 to 2, or changing from 2 to 1; direction of travel is not fixed.

Comment: *Biconfluence* and triconfluence*?

Comment: I disagree that *bifurcate* or *trifurcate* can be used to denote the opposite of their explicit meaning. *Bifurcate* means to split into two branches or paths. If you were to detail the directions when traveling *to* Logan *from* the east, you would not still say that the freeway bifurcates, but that it converges 20 miles from Logan. There does not seem to be any direct official antonym for these words, but I am willing to accept *biconverge* and *triconverge* as somewhat useful neologisms.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use the word "**(Re)anneal**" to describe that phenomenon – (re)connections in computer networks are a constant.  However, that's the term I used a lot when studying biochemistry, where it refers to the process in which two single strands of DNA recombine into their bonded helical form.

More generally, there's "**consilience**", which roughly means "a springing together" – like disparate facts suddenly lining up to tell a story, or maybe an interdisciplinary tapestry of the sort used by the Game's players in Hermann Hesse's timeless book *Magister Ludi* ("*The Glass Bead Game*").